# How to make gameobject not fall using rigidbody but without disabling gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am using a rigidbody component attached to my game Object and I don't want to disable gravity but the game object keeps on falling. Moreover the enemy capsule just falls below the ground in my game. Im a little new to unity. The game I am making is with the help of the (Learning c# by developing games unity 2021) this is the 6th version.
The script for the player behaviour is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerBehavoiur : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float MoveSpeed = 10f;
        public float RotateSpeed = 75f;
        public int hp = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// stores a rigidbody component for a gameobject
        /// </summary>
        private Rigidbody _rb;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            _rb.useGravity = true;
        }
        private float _hInput1;
        private float _vInput1;
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            /*MoveForward(_hInput1);
            RotateUpWards(_vInput1);
            */
        }
        /*public void MoveForward(float _vInput)
        {
            _vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed;
            this.transform.Translate()
        }
        public void RotateUpWards(float _hInput)
        {
            _hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * RotateSpeed;
            this.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * _hInput * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        */
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            SetVerticalDirection();
            SetHorizontalDirection();
            //makes the object move by horizontal input in the up direction
            Vector3 rotation = Vector3.up * _hInput1;
            /*this is the rotation of the game object 
             * moving up and then going at a fixed frame rate
             */
            Quaternion angleRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            //this takes vertical input and addes the position and makes it move forward
            //the vertical input is the vertical axis whihc moves at a defined rate tht we can define
            _rb.MovePosition(this.transform.position + 
                this.transform.forward * _vInput1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            /*the move rotation moves using the rigibody rotation times the 
             * horizontal input times and moves up and rotates at the rotate speed rate
             */
            _rb.MoveRotation(_rb.rotation * angleRotation);
        }
        void SetVerticalDirection()
        {
            _vInput1 = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed;
        }
        void SetHorizontalDirection()
        {
            _hInput1 = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * RotateSpeed;
        }
        /*Horizontal: ad
         * Vertical: ws
         */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Inspector, you can set gravity scale to 0. Or set the mass to 0. If none works, go to the Rigdid Body and use the Constraints and freeze the y position. this will stop it from falling

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot set `Mass = 0` it will revert to `1e-07` or `0.0000001` minimum, Best thing is to use `Constraints` and freeze y position or simply set Rigidbody to `IsKinematic` = true

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently studying this book. You should check the third box in the RigidBody Freeze Rotation.

[image: Screenshot from unity]

Comment: thanks for the help guys but freeze rotation would mean I cant turn it left or right but Ill still check

Comment: In this case, uncheck the box X